# Failed to open stream autoload.php Facebook SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, autoload

I'm trying to upgrade my app from PHP SDK v2.0 to latest PHP SDK v4. My current version of PHP is 5.4. I've upload the PHP SDK to www/games/facebook/client. I get the following message in the php_error.log:

```
 PHP Warning:  require(facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /files/www/games/facebook/classes/RedSocialCore/wrappers/FacebookWrapper.php on line 16

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /files/www/games/facebook/classes/RedSocialCore/wrappers/FacebookWrapper.php on line 16
```

This is the initialization:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require ('facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

I'll appreciate any advice

Comment: It say that the file facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php doesn't exists. Does it exists?

Comment: Yes is inside 'www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4'. Thanks

Comment: Where is the initialization code that you displayed above?

Comment: its on \www\games\facebook\classes\RedSocialCore\wrappers\FacebookWrapper.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', $base.'/www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require ($base.'/www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

Comment: Looking at your path error I don't think it is pointed correctly from FacebookWrapper.php.

Comment: Thanks!. I fixed paths like this:                          define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/files/www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require ('/files/www/games/facebook/client/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php');